# International to U.S. wire transfer

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer

Is there a limit by government regulations on large amount transfer from international account to U.S. account. Same person on both accounts. Or is limit set by bank?

Answer (score 2):

There is no legal limit, and banks can handle 9 digit amounts.

Note that if the money appears from thin air, the IRS might appear and want it treated as *taxable income*, potentially with fees and interest for previous years. If the money/asset was already yours before, it will be on your previous tax returns somewhere, be it as ‘foreign assets’ or ‘gift’ or whatever (unless you committed ‘tax fraud’ by not listing it).

Comment: Important to mention the need to report it.

Answer (score 0):

The government of country you transfer from may have  some regulations.

E.g., [South Korea](http://www.koreatimesus.com/s-korea-to-double-international-money-transfer-limit-to-2000/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180804034200/http://www.koreatimesus.com/s-korea-to-double-international-money-transfer-limit-to-2000/)):

> The South Korean government plans to allow individuals to freely send up to $2,000 abroad per transaction without reporting to the government, double the current amount.

Comment: _reporting it_ does not mean it's not allowed. Of course it is reported in the US too, but it's still legal and possible.